# enable git Dreamweaver on MacOS

Tags: macos, github, dreamweaver

am trying to enable git Dreamweaver  get  please wait , Git is being ...

[image]

my Preferences

[image]

the path of git /usr/bin/git working good with mac terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix it by
 path of terminal /Applications/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2019/Adobe Dreamweaver 2019.app/Contents/www/extensions/default/brackets-git/shell/terminal.osa

and git path   /usr/local/bin/git

[image]
and restart mac